# Laravel ViewComposer - Undefined variable: countUnreadNotifications

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I am trying to use ViewComposers so that I can display data in layouts\header

App\http\View\Composers\NotificationsComposer

```
<?php

namespace App\http\View\Composers;
use App\Models\Notification\UserNotification;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class NotificationsComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $userCompany    = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $userID         = Auth::user()->id;

        $countUnreadNotifications = UserNotification::where('send_to', $userID)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->count();
        $unreadNotifications = UserNotification::where('send_to', $userID)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
        $allNotifications = UserNotification::where('send_to', $userID)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        return $view->with([
            'countUnreadNotifications' => $countUnreadNotifications,
            'unreadNotifications ' => $unreadNotifications, 
            'allNotifications ' => $allNotifications
        ]);
     }
```

AppServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\Notification\UserNotification;
use App\Http\View\Composers\NotificationsComposer;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
        public function boot()
        {
            View::composer(['layouts.header'], NotificationsComposer::class);
        }
}

layouts\header.blade

<span class="dropdown-item dropdown-header">You have {{ $countUnreadNotifications }} unread notifications</span>
```

When I logged in I got this error:

> Undefined variable: countUnreadNotifications (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\layouts\header.blade.php)

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is here  'unreadNotifications '. the is a space before the parenthesis. So I removed the space 'unreadNotifications' and everything works fine.  Thank you